# Proving a group is $PSL(2,q)$ with $q>3$ odd.

Tags: group-theory

How can I prove the following theorem

> If $G$ is a nonabelian simple group with Sylow $2$-subgroups being of order $4$
>   then $G=PSL(2,q) $ where $q>3$  is odd.

with the help of this theorem:

> Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$. If $|N|$
>   and $|G : N|$ are relatively prime then $G$ has a subgroup $H$ such that $G = NH$ with $N\cap H = 1.$

Comment: I edited your question. Please make sure it is what you are asking; it seems you want to use the second stated result as a lemma to prove the first? Also in the future please refrain from using all-caps in the title (or anywhere for that matter).

Comment: I think it very unlikely that you can! Chapter 15 of Gorenstein's book "Finite Groups" is devoted to the special case of this result when the Sylow $2$-subgroup is self-centralizing.

Comment: What's the intended connection between both theorems? Rough idea would be enough (and appreciated a lot).